# Residual sum of squares, two different equations, why are they equal?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, residuals, sums-of-squares

One definition of the Residual Sum of Squares is:

$$
S_r = (y-X\hat{\beta})^T(y-X\hat{\beta})
$$

And I think I understand it.

Now I have seen a different definition:

$$
S_r = y^Ty- \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}
$$

I think they supposed to be equal but I can't see why.

I can write (I leave out the \hat on $\beta$ to make the typing easier):

$$
\begin{aligned}
S_r &= y^T(y-X\beta) - \beta^TX^T(y-X\beta)\\
&= y^Ty - y^TX\beta - \beta^TX^T y + \beta^TX^TX\beta
\end{aligned}
$$

and then to make both equations equal I would need to see that $\beta^TX^TX\beta = \beta^TX^T y$ which I don't.

How, do you show that the equations are equal?

Comment: Hint: $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$.

Comment: why I am getting different results? set.seed(0)
x=matrix(runif(30),ncol=3)
beta=matrix(runif(3),ncol=1)
y=matrix(runif(10),ncol=1)

crossprod(x %*% beta - y)

t(y) %*% y - t(beta) %*% t(x) %*% x %*% beta

Comment: @hxd1011 You cannot just pick some arbitrary values for beta. Again, see my hint.

Comment: So it is not linear algebra, but assume $\beta$ is optimal !!

Comment: @hxd1011 This code exemplifies the situation.  Run it: `n <- 10;
x <- seq(-2, 2, length.out=n);
beta <- c(1,-2);
y <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x + rnorm(n);
fit <- lm(y ~ x);
Sr.1 <- sum(resid(fit)^2);
Sr.2 <- sum(y^2) - sum(predict(fit)^2);
print(c(RSS.1=Sr.1, RSS.2=Sr.2))`  This is just the Pythagorean Theorem: the first formula is the square of one leg of a right triangle while the second formula subtracts the square of the other leg from the square of the hypotenuse.

Comment: @whuber thanks. in your example `y` is "derived" from $\beta$ and `x`. So, same point with Wolfgang.

Comment: @hxd1011 I cannot tell what you are trying to say.  That code simulates from the linear regression model with a $\beta$ you specify.  It computes the two quantities in the question, using the two formulas for $S_r$, and prints them out. You can verify that it always prints the same values (up to floating point rounding error, if any). Since this is purely linear algebra (geometry, actually) you could let `y` be any vector you like: the two quantities will still be equal.

Comment: @whuber thanks I get it now, the reason I did not get the same value is I pick arbitrary values for beta

Comment: @hxd1011 That is not the reason, the reason is you are using the "true" $\beta$ and not the estimated $\hat{\beta}=(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In math, generally there are more than one way to prove a equation. I think the previous Answers are correct, but differ from your approach. Your approach is correct also, but you need one more step.

At first, you missed hat on $\beta$ in your last equation. Using the fact that $\hat \beta =(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, we have

$\hat\beta^TX^Ty=y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = \hat\beta^TX^TX\hat\beta$

So finished your steps.

Answer (score 3):

The most compact way to see the equality is to use the orthogonal projection matrix $P = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and the residual-maker matrix $M = I-P$. Both these matrices are symmetric, $P'=P,\;\; M'=M$ and idempotent $PP=P,\;\; MM = M$. 
We have

$$X\hat{\beta} = Py, \;\;y-X\hat{\beta}= My$$

Then 
$$S_r = (y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta}) = (My)'(My) = y'M'My = y'My$$

$$ = y'(I-P)y = y'y - y'Py = y'y-(Py)'Py=y'y- \hat{\beta}'X'X\hat{\beta}$$

Answer (score 0):

As @whuber said in the comment, it is essentially [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Where Let error

$$e=y-X\hat\beta$$

and prediction

$$
p=X\hat\beta
$$

The first equation is 
$$
e^Te=\|e\|^2
$$
and second equation is $y^Ty-p^Tp=\|y\|^2-\|p\|^2$. Because vector $e$ and vector $p$ are perpendicular, we have $\|y\|^2-\|p\|^2=\|e\|^2$.

Details can also be found in Gilbert Strangs's linear algebra book. [Sample chapter here](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf)

[image]

Comment: The definition of $p$ in your answer seems to miss the $\text{^}$ in $\hat{\beta}$. The distinction between $\beta$ and $\hat{\beta}$ is crucial to correctly disentangling the OP's misunderstanding.

Comment: You have introduced a new problem above the previous one; the term "error" would apply to the term as you originally had it, to $y-X\beta$. If you really do mean $y-X\hat{\beta}$ (as it now says), that's normally referred to as *residual*, not *error*. Errors are unobserved, residuals are in effect an estimate of the errors. Again, the distinction is important (and I think related the original misunderstanding in the question).